# Specializing function template for both std::string and char*

Tags: c++, string, templates, char

As the title says I want to specialize a function template for both string and char pointer, so far I did [this](http://www.ideone.com/Fi6KF) but I can not figure out passing the string parameters by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
template<typename T> void xxx(T param)
{
std::cout << "General : "<< sizeof(T)  << std::endl;
}

template<> void xxx<char*>(char* param)
{
std::cout << "Char ptr: "<< strlen(param) << std::endl;
}

template<> void xxx<const char* >(const char*  param)
{
std::cout << "Const Char ptr : "<< strlen(param)<<  std::endl;
}

template<> void xxx<const std::string & >(const std::string & param)
{
std::cout << "Const String : "<< param.size()<<  std::endl;
}

template<> void xxx<std::string >(std::string param)
{
std::cout << "String : "<< param.size()<<  std::endl;
}


int main()
{
        xxx("word");
        std::string aword("word");
        xxx(aword);

        std::string const cword("const word");
        xxx(cword);
}
```

Also `template<> void xxx<const std::string & >(const std::string & param)` thing just does not working.

If I rearranged the opriginal template to accept parameters as `T&` then the `char *` is required to be `char * &` which is not good for static text in code.

Please help !

Comment: Now it doesn't compile! You need to put `<string.h>` back, for `strlen`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doesn’t the following work?

```
template<>
void xxx<std::string>(std::string& param)
{
    std::cout << "String : "<< param.size()<<  std::endl;
}
```

And the same for `const std::string`?

That said, [***don’t* specialize a function template**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) if you have the choice (and you usually do!). Instead, just overload the function:

```
void xxx(std::string& param)
{
    std::cout << "String : "<< param.size()<<  std::endl;
}
```

Notice, this is *not* a template. In 99% of the cases, this is fine.

(Something else, C++ doesn’t have a header `<string.h>` except for backwards compatibility to C. The C-string header in C++ is called `<cstring>` (note the leading `c`) but from your code it look as though you actually mean the header `<string>` (no leading `c`).)

Comment: Ah sorry for the `<string.h>`. I will fix it.

Comment: A link would be nice as to why it shouldn't be specialized, so here it is: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @stefaanv: nice, will include.

Comment: @sad_man: no, it's in Konrads answer and to be honest, I wasn't aware of this before...

Comment: Have you compiled this? g++ 4.4.0 doesn't accept it. It gives the error message: `error: template-id 'xxx<std::string>' for 'void xxx(std::string&)' does not match any template declaration`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a distillation of what I find surprising:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void f(T param) { std::cout << "General" << std::endl ; }
template<> void f(int& param) { std::cout << "int&" << std::endl ; }

int main() {
  float x ; f (x) ;
  int y ; f (y) ;
  int& z = y ; f (z) ;
}
```

This prints "General" 3 times. The first time (float) is expected, the third time (int&) is a surprise. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: This is the problem I have with std::string&. There is something wrong with passing referenced types in a template. I wish somebody explains it.

Answer (score 0):

is really risky try to coding using compiler-based-type-conversions

one thing is the use of a template based, and other is the use of polymorph with different types.

depend of the compiler you can get different behaviors.